# Can 誰にも be used in positive verb?

Tags: grammar

Most examples I read, 誰にも is always used in negative verbs. Is there a case in which 誰にも is used in positive verbs?

Comment: 誰でもできる is more common than 誰にもできる in  positive verbs.

Comment: ^ でも「誰にも欠点はある。」「誰にも覚えがあるはず」とかだったら、「誰でも」より「誰にも」のほうがいいように思います。

Comment: I feel the both でも and にも in your sentence will do but I think only でも is natural in like 誰でも話せる、誰でも泳げる、誰でも泣ける.

Comment: @chocolate 確かにその場合に「誰でも」を使うのは少し違和感があるんですが、私の感覚ですと「誰にでも欠点はある」「誰にでも覚えがあるはず」の方が自然な気がします。

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**「[誰]{だれ}にも + Verb in Positive Form」**

is indeed in active use even among professional writers as you see below.  Whether or not one should prescriptively call it "correct" in a place like this would be a different matter.  Truth is, however, that form is quite common currently in the real Japanese-speaking world.

So, my answer would have to be: ***Yes, it can.***

That is not to say, however, that Japanese-learners should use it whenever they feel like using it.  In fact, I recommend that they not use it too often until they are fluent enough and have developed their feelings for the words and phrases.

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [messia.com](http://messia.com/reiki/book5/cover.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but it's limited to a few things like in the accepted answer above, because of the に. Without the に, it becomes 誰もが:

誰もが知っているような歴史人物 — a historical character everyone knows.

These are literary usages, though. In normal conversational Japanese 誰でも is used.

Answer (score -1):

No, `誰にも` is only used in negative verbs.